# isLibrary on Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Good day, assuming we have been using *Eclipse*, when importing Android Projects which you only wanted to make it as Library, you check the checkbox isLibrary. Now I am using Android Studio and I have been importing libraries from maven central and I'm very fine with it. My question now is, **When adding a module on Android Studio, Where do I find the isLibrary option?**

I might be confused on some aspects here but I am still a novice in the new environment. I know very little about *Gradle*. There is this Java Library option on New Module but it creates a new, not import a new.

[image]

Comment: did I understood well that you want to make new library project independently of app? So you don't want to add library module to your app project?

Comment: Add a module to my App Sir as Library  huhu

Comment: I got an external library folder made from other's project however I wanted to import it on my app as a library only

Comment: so you want to have project that contains one module that is app code and  another that is library code? That way when you open Project you will have both but in separate modules?

Comment: Hmmm to make it simple I want to import a module into my project which is marked as IsLibrary, like what eclipse does,,,

Comment: hopefully answer will be enough to solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I guess you already have written some application code so you want to start writing new library module that will be part of the same project. That project will at the end have structure like this: [image: Library module in Android project (Android Studio)]

To add library (that you will write) to existing project do the following: 
**File** -> **New** -> **New Module** and dialog will appear similar to one that you attached. You should choose **Android Library** [image: Create New Module Dialog]

After you click next, you should enter name in "Application/Library name" (in my case it was "My Test Library") and module name will be filled based on that automatically. Choose min SDK (under text field where you entered name) and click next. On next screen choose if you will add some pre defined components (like blank activity or activity with fragment) to your library or in case if library will contain no UI elements but just some business logic choose "Add No Activity". In case you need later you can always add it. Depending on previous choice either you need to enter activity name (if you want to add it) or you will click finish if you don't want activities in your lib.

when you eventually come to finish, gradle will start rebuilding project and preparing files and inform you once it finish with popup describing results. At that moment you should see something similar to first screenshot in this answer.

In case you want to import existing library code, you should choose:
File -> New -> Import Module and choose path to existing library. Android Studio will than ask you to confirm that it should replace jars and sources with dependencies (if possible) and create camelCase names. There should't be any additional troubles during this process. [image]

This is all done and looks like on screenshots in the latest Android Studio v1.3.1.. Hopefully it helps to you and others ;)

P.S. Not sure if this was your mistake or you simply missed it,but you shouldn't choose java library instead of android library. I actually don't know what result did you get by doing so but I guess it would make new module with one package, and one class in it, but without manifests and res folders and without dependency on android apis (support library for instance) which are all created when you choose **Android library**